# Ramda Get values from nested objects inside array

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to get values from a nested object using Ramda but I just started to use it. To get the testArray I used:

```
R.find(R.propEq('type', 'checklist'))((data))
```

Data is another array with different types but I need to focus only on 'checklist' type. I would like to get only items which have property "checked": true.

This is my array which I am trying to transform.

```
const testArray = [{
  "type": "checklist",
  "data": {
    "items": [
      { "id": "r-1", "checked": true },
      { "id": "r-2", "checked": false }
    ]
  }
}]
```

**Edit:**
I made another step using:

```
R.path(['data', 'items'])
```

I got only items that I can simply filter. But I am not sure if it is the correct way to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```js
const checkedItems = pipe (
  find (propEq('type', 'checklist')),
  defaultTo ({data: {items: []}}),
  path (['data', 'items']),
  filter (prop ('checked'))
)

const testArray = [{type: "checklist", data: {items: [{id: "r-1", checked: true }, {id: "r-2", checked: false}]}}]

console .log (
  checkedItems (testArray)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, find, propEq, defaultTo, path, filter, prop} = R</script>
```

Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors) is designed around this idea of a functional pipeline, where the result of one call is piped into the next.  Here we use the `propEq` you started with, pipe it to a `defaultTo` call, which gives a sensible default if the previous step finds nothing, then to the `path` statement you used, and then finally to a `filter` call, which keeps only those where the `checked` property is `true`.

If you're absolutely certain about your data, you can skip the `defaultTo` step.

The `filter` call could also be `filter (propEq ('checked', true))`, but since `prop ('checked')` whould be returning a boolean, I went with the simpler version.

Comment: Thank you. So I was close... :D